# Make an class based on JSON result

Tags: android, json

this below json result sent from server for my app, `all_food` is object which keys started with string with number such as `list1`, `list2` or `list9` and `lists` nested `all_foods` have an number for keys, this structure is very difficult for me to know how can i make class structure for that

```
{
  "all_foods": {
    "list1": {
      "1": "---------------",
      "5": "---------------"
    },
    "list2": {
      "1": "---------------",
      "3": "---------------"
    },
    "list9": {
      "1": "---------------",
      "4": "---------------",
      "6": "---------------"
    }
  },
  "show_mixture": false,
  "User_status": 2,
  "lists": [
    {
      "UserDailyList": {
        "id": "142885",
        "created": "2017-08-06 22:12:56",
        "modified": "2017-08-06 22:12:56"
      },
      "foods": {
        "1": {
          "meal": "---------------",
          "food": "---------------"
        },
        "2": {
          "meal": "---------------",
          "food": "---------------"
        },
        "3": {
          "meal": "---------------",
          "food": "---------------"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "error": 1,
  "message": "",
  "condition": {
    "code": "7",
    "message": "-------",
    "token": 10
  }
}
```

how can i make this structure on java class? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, two ways

You could learn the whole object modelling in Java, create POJO class which contain another class and so on.

Or you could use an online tool create the POJO from any JSON.

Two google search results for you, you can search for

> JSON to POJO Online

and check more links there.

[Link 1](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
[Link 2](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/)

Comment: i tested that on this links, but i dont get correct result from them. for example `all_foods` objects, they are sample and i dont know how many data stored on that, then i can't create class for them

Comment: all_foods is an object which contains other objects and does not contain a list at all. If you want you can add a new getter which returns the count.

Comment: if we suppose all_foods is static, this code`http://paste.debian.net/980212/` is correct?

Comment: Yes. Given a chance to modify the JSON, I would include a list of objects, instead of hard wired dependencies.

Comment: unfortunately i get null for `all_food`

Comment: all_foods it is, you will have to name your variables according to the name of the keys in JSON to start with.. I am sorry, I did not check it too much in detail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151251/discussion-between-aksappy-and-mahdi-pishguy).

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using GSON

```
class FoodResponse{
    @SerializedName("all_foods")
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> allFood;

    @SerializedName("show_mixture")
    boolean showMixture;
    ///.. and so on

}
```

usually, with such unnecessarily complex and poorly designed JSON I recommend deserializing it like this:

```
new Gson().fromJson(json, Map.class); //or just Object.class
```

which returns a LinkedTreeMap of LinkedTreeMaps of LinkedTreeMaps (..n)
which you can browse by key/value and extract the data you need.

You won't be able to create a proper response model for a JSON that hasn't been generated from a proper JSON model on the backend. It is a common practice to fist-fight backend devs to have them send good json :)

Comment: `Map.class` class is an empty class?

Comment: @Nick          Out of curiosity: Which are the disadvantages in the provided JSON data example?

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy what?

Comment: @John Inconsistent naming, unnecessary boxing, incorrect structure

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Basic skeleton of pojo class    
    class AllFoods {
        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String>[] arrayOfList = new List[3];  //In case if we know how     //many arraylist items are added, 
        String show_mixture;
        String User_status;
        List<String> l1sts = new ArrayList<>();
        String UserDailyList;
        String id;
        String created;
        String modified;
        List<String> foodsArray= new List[3];  //if we know the range
        List<String> foodsList = new ArrayList<>();
        String error;
        String message;
        List<String> condition = new ArrayList<>();
        }  
//Then we need to have constuctors and add the values and have them in arrayofList
```